# Variable containing classobj - good style?

Tags: python, coding-style

Python style question.

Sometimes I assign classes to variables so I can instantiate them elsewhere, eg:

```
class GuitarItem():
    pass

class SuperClass():
    def get_instance(self):
        return self.Item()

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    Item = GuitarItem

class SubClass2(SuperClass):
    Item = PianoItem
```

Is this good style? Am I missing a more idiomatic way to do this? It worries me because `item` is not capitalised (as it is a variable) so it 'looks' like a method call.

UPDATE: As per comments from Hyperboreus I am capitalising the `Item` which looks more sensible to me as well. Otherwise this seems absolutely fine.

Comment: Every class already has a name (the one it was declared with and which was passed to `type()`). So there is nothing bad about giving them more names as need be.

Comment: @Hyperboreus so the above does not look weird to you.. you would write it the same way?

Comment: I would capitalize the variable. Something like `Thing = LinuxThing if os == 'linux' else NoLinuxThing`, being `LinuxThing` and `NoLinuxThing` classes. But don't ask me about style. I get frequently bashed here on SO because I don't stick to PEP-8.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Thanks for confirming this. This also makes sense to me, but wanted to check with the hive mind first :-)

Comment: Neverthess the `self` in your `item_instance = self.item()` is not defines... I guess it went original inside some method?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Is there any way round that? My IDE is also complaining about that to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47511/discussion-between-horselover-fat-and-hyperboreus)

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yes, you're right, originally it was in a method, I adjusted the question to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure, but maybe you are looking for something along these lines. And yes, why not give a class another name in another scope.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

class GuitarItem: pass

class PianoItem: pass

class SuperClass:
    def makeItem (self): #or whatever you want to do with the Item class
        return type (self).Item ()

class SubClass (SuperClass): Item = GuitarItem

class SubClass2 (SuperClass): Item = PianoItem

print (SubClass ().makeItem () )
print (SubClass2 ().makeItem () )
```

This will first create a Guitar and then a Piano.

Answer (score 2):

To address your main question :

> Sometimes I assign classes to variables so I can instantiate them
>   elsewhere (...) Is this good style? Am I missing a more idiomatic way
>   to do this?

Python's classes (as well as functions, methods, modules etc) are plain object, just like anything else, so yes it is "good style" and no, there's no "more idiomatic way".

> It worries me because item is not capitalised (as it is a variable) so
>   it 'looks' like a method call.

It actually ends up being a method call (it's calling the `__call__` method of the metaclass, which in turn calls the `__new__` method of the class). Also FWIW you don't care whether `item` is actually a class, any callable returning the expected object would (and will) work as well, so it makes no sense CamelCasing it.

Comment: +1. And your last paragraph is interesting. Let's say I have `class Item: pass` and somewhere else `ThisSpecialItemClass = Item` or `this_special_item_class = Item` with out camelcase as you propose. What is the difference between the name `Item` and `this_special_item_class`? Aren't they both names for a class and should be spelled in the same casing?

Comment: @Hyperboreus it seems logical to capitalise the variable as they are both names for classes but would love to see a guideline on this if it exists. PEP8 doesn't seem to clarify it (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @Hyperboreus: the difference is that `Item` is the class canonical name - the one you'll see if you `print Item`. FWIW, the convention for `classmethods` and most functions / methods that expect a class as argument is to name the argument `cls` (lowercase).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thank you. I see your point and think that your argumentation is more congruent than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using factory method pattern, because its very similar to what you've done and industry knows this pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

```
class GuitarItem(): pass 
class PianoItem(): pass

class SuperClass():

    def __init__(self)
        self.item_instance = self.new_item()

    def new_item(self):
        """Explain why it should provide item."""
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclass of SuperClass must provide new_item method")


class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def new_item(self):
        return GuitarItem()

class SubClass2(SuperClass):
    def new_item(self):
        return PianoItem()
```

Comment: OK, what does the 'Factory pattern' translation of the above code look like? I don't really 'get' what many OOP design patterns look like in Python so this will help me a lot.

Comment: The fact that classes and functions are first class citizens in python, eliminates the need of such abominations as factory patterns. I think those are mostly a Java disease.

Comment: OK, perhaps it won't help me then ;-)